# Singular values of rounding matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

I have a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ with $\text{rank}(A)=n$. I do a rounding operation (rounding to nearest integer) on each element of $A$. So new rounded matrix $B$ is actually $B=A+E$ where $E \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is the matrix of fractional values that rounds $A$ to $B$. For any such $E$, can we say anything about its singular values ? Also can we find, lowest possible value of $\alpha$ such that $\|E\| \leq \alpha$ ?

Comment: There are inequalities for the singular values of $A + E$ in terms of those of $A$ and those of $E$.  What exactly does $\|E\|$ mean to you?  Do you have a preferred matrix norm (spectral norm? Frobenius norm?)

Comment: I will like to know about such inequalities.  Frobenius norm is preferable but if different results exist for other norms then I will like to know about them too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notably, all we can say about the entries of $E$ is that they all have magnitude at most $5$.  Of course, this means that the Frobenius norm satisfies $\|E\| \leq (0.5) \cdot n = \frac n2$ (and $\alpha = \frac n2$ is indeed the lowest possible upper bound).  We easily get the result that all singular values of $E$ are at most $\frac n2$.  Moreover, we could note that in general,
$$
\|E\| = \sqrt{\sigma_1^2(E) + \cdots + \sigma_n^2(E)} \leq \frac n2
$$
we can't say much more about the singular values of $E$ directly.

Bhatia's *Matrix Analysis* provides a useful result:

> **(using problem III.6.5)**  For any two operators $A, E$ and any two indices $i, j$ such that $i + j = n +1$, we have
>   $$
> \sigma_{i+j-1}(A + E) \leq \sigma_i(A)+ \sigma_j(E)\\
> \sigma_{i}(A + E) \geq |\sigma_{i + j-1}(A) - \sigma_j(E)|
> $$